# BizTalk Event Viewer Report

Tags: powershell, biztalk

I have my PowerShell script ready for monitor Event Viewer for  “BizTalk Server” and I also attached generated output as screen shot.

Can you help me out where my code is missing for email alert through 1 common output instead of individual error for every `BizTalk Server” error.

I appreciate your time to get some information on my code and it’s really help me out to set script to my environment.

```
$getEventLog = Get-Eventlog -log application -after ((get-date).AddHours(-0.25)) -EntryType Error | Where-Object {($_.Source -eq 'BizTalk Server')}
[INT]$i = 1
#Create mail content
$mailBody = ""
Foreach ($log in $getEventLog)
{
    $mailBody += "<th><b>Event log error message: " + $log.Index + "</b></th>"
    $mailBody += "<table style='boder:0px 0px 0px 0px;'>"

    $mailBody += "<TR style='background-color:white;'><TD>Time</TD>"
    $mailBody += "<TD>" + $log.TimeWritten + "</TD></TR>"

    $mailBody += "<TR style='background-color:rgb(245,245,245);';><TD>Source</TD>"
    $mailBody += "<TD>" + $log.Source + "</TD></TR>"

    $mailBody += "<TR style='background-color:white;'><TD>Message</TD>"
    $mailBody += "<TD>" + $log.Message + "</TD></TR>"

    $mailBody += "<TR style='background-color:rgb(245,245,245);'><TD>Machine Name</TD>"
    $mailBody += "<TD>" + $log.MachineName + "</TD></TR>"

    $mailBody += "</table>"
    $mailBody += "<BR><BR>"

    $i ++
}

$count = $i - 1;
$mailTextReport = "This report was generated because there are "+ $count  + " error messages in the Event Viewer that require your attention."

# HTML Format for Output
$HTMLmessage = @"
    <font color=""black"" face=""Arial"" size=""3"">
    <h1 style='font-family:arial;'><b>BizTalk Event Viewer Report</b></h1>
    <p style='font: .8em ""Lucida Grande"", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>$mailTextReport</p>
    <br><br>
    <style type=""text/css"">body{font: .8em ""Lucida Grande"", Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    ol{margin:0;}
    table{width:80%;}
    thead{}
    thead th{font-size:120%;text-align:left;}
    th{border-bottom:2px solid rgb(79,129,189);border-top:2px solid rgb(79,129,189);padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;}
    tr{padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;border:none;}
    #middle{background-color:#900;}
    </style>
    <body BGCOLOR=""white"">
    $mailBody
    </body>
    "@
```

Redundant Error list repeated 9 times in email alert

![Redundant Error list repeated 9 times in email alert ][1]

I need output look like below screen shot.
Error list need to be single time and use new table for each error found in event viewer

![Error list need to be singal time and use new table for each error found in event viewer][2]

Comment: Possibly the HTML you are generating is malformed.  Can you add a snippet of what that looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the foreach you're reading (**$log** in **$getEventLog**) but in the code where HTML is generated, you're assigning **$getEventLog**.*Property* instead the **$log**.*Property* for each loop, so you're putting all the error content together all times.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for answer now it's working properly ! I forgot to change $log into the loop .